# Выбор связанного поста в ACF форме (acf_form)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, acf

Я вывел форму ACF, которая создает новый пост кастомного типа "Недвижимость"

```
 <?php acf_form_head()?>
  <?php acf_form($settings = array(


  'id' => 'estate-form',
  'post_id' => 'new_post',
  'new_post' => array(
      'post_type'   => 'estate',
      'post_status' => 'publish'),
  'field_groups' => array('group_62befc49dd97b'),   
  'fields' => false,
  'post_title' => true,
  'post_content' => true,
  'form' => true,
  'return' => '',
  'submit_value' => __("Добавить недвижимость", 'acf'),
  'updated_message' => __("Пост обновлен", 'acf'),
  'label_placement' => 'top',
  'instruction_placement' => 'label',
  'honeypot' => true,
  'html_updated_message'  => '<div id="message" class="updated"><p>%s</p></div>',
  'html_submit_button'  => '<input type="submit" class="acf-button button button-primary button-large" value="%s" />',
  'html_submit_spinner' => '<span class="acf-spinner"></span>',
  'kses'  => true
      
)); ?>
```

У постов типа "Недвижимость" есть связанные посты кастомного типа "Города".
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать связанный пост при добавлении нового поста в форме? И как добавить возможность добавить изображение поста?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/ ?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению. Условие в том, что родительский пост нельзя создавать через ACF - такое условие клиента

Comment: Там и не надо "создавать пост через ACF" (я вообще не представлю кому такое может в голову прийти). Там создаётся ПОЛЕ для связи (relationship, отношения).

Comment: Но фишка в том, что отношения постов уже настроено  без плагинов таким образом - 

`add_action('add_meta_boxes', function () {
    add_meta_box( 'post_city', 'Город недвижимости', 'post_city_metabox', 'estate', 'side', 'low'  );
});

function post_city_metabox( $post ){

    $cities = get_posts(array( 'post_type'=>'city', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'orderby'=>'post_title', 'order'=>'ASC' ));
        foreach( $cities as $city ){
 <li><label><input type="radio" name="post_parent" value="'. $city->ID .'" '. checked($city->ID, $post->post_parent, 0) .'> '. esc_html($city->post_title)`